# Correct use of numpy interpolate

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I need to perform some filtering to a non-uniformly spaced grid in python. Thus, I interpolate the non-uniform grid into a uniform one by means of griddata:

```
zi = interpolate.griddata((xin, yin), zin, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')
```

Then, after zi has been filtered I need to back interpolate the mesh to the original xin, yin points. If I do this:

```
zout = interpolate.griddata((xi, yi), zi, (xin[None,:], yin[:,None]), method='cubic')
```

I get some errors I do not understand, related to "qhull precision warning", and "qhull error" in Delaunay triangulation.

Does anybody know how can I fix this problem? can it be related to the fact that (xin,yin) are not ordered? Thanks.

[UPDATE]
I'll try to clarify what the input data is. Input data is a cartesian mesh that has been refined in the center (both in x and y axes). As long as I want to filter it, I need to interpolate an uniformly sampled version of it, and the perform another interpolation to go back from the uniformly sampled to the refined.

xin, yin, zin are 1D arrays, as well as xi and yi. zi (output of griddata) is a 2D array.

Comment: Can you add some sample input data to your post? You can generate random data of the same shape as your input if you like.

Comment: Try to use `method='nearest'` and see if you get this error...

Comment: What is your data like? Scattered points in 2-D, or is the data ordered on a regular grid? What are `xin.shape`, `yin.shape`, `zin.shape`? Without this information, it is difficult to say whether you are using the function correctly or not. The "Qhull error" typically means that your data lies along a single line in 2-D, and hence cannot be used for any sort of interpolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second call to `griddata` is incorrect. It expects `xi` and `yi` are the coordinates for each point, and that `zi[i,:]` are the values corresponding to point `(xi[i], yi[i])`.

Apparently, your `xi` and `yi` arrays happen to have the same number `N` of entries, so you don't get an error immediately. There's no way the function can guess that you actually wanted it to do something else.